# HLS encrypted AES-128 - IOS device problem

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I encrypted our HLS movie in AES-128. 
On all devices it works but on IOS (iphone and Ipad) no.

below is my m3u8 file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://xxxx/xxxx/xxxxx/x/xxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx.key",IV=0x4d347130965af9bba4349829013bb440
#EXTINF:2.000000,
1_1080p_000.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
1_1080p_001.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,
1_1080p_002.ts
#EXTINF:2.000000,

    …

.
```

has anyone had the same problem and can tell me how to solve it?
Thank you

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. Please post logs, or error messages, or a sample we can test.

Answer (score 0):

I checked with the safari web inspector and I can't understand, the key is downloaded correctly but stops when it downloads the first target[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgU9r.png)t